# Capture character from string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have this string:

```
"<div class='name-and-date'><strong>Bartholome Hilpert MD - Dec 21, 
12:38 PM Eastern</div></strong><div class='note-contents'>- 
another</div><div> Attachment: <p class='attachment'>N/A</p></div></span>"
```

How can I capture this value:

```
N/A
```

As you can see I want to scan for what is the value of the `<p class='attachment'>`

Attempt:

```
conversation.scan(/<p class='attachment'>/)
```

But that doesn't get the value of what is in the p tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do this more often than not, I would consider using an HTML parser such as [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/) because writing regex for every such need is painful.

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = Nokogiri::HTML("<div class='name-and-date'><strong>Bartholome Hilpert MD - Dec 21, 12:38 PM Eastern</div></strong><div class='note-contents'>- another</div><div> Attachment: <p class='attachment'>N/A</p></div></span>")
html.at_css('p.attachment').text # => "N/A"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can match `N/A` with

```
conversation[/(?<=<p class='attachment'>).*?(?=<\/p>)/]                          
 #=> "N/A"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`conversation.scan(/(?<=<p class='attachment'>).*?(?=<\/p>)/).first`